# A question about tail probabilities of identically distributed variables.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, distribution-tails

I have $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be identically distributed but not necessarily independent random variables with $E[X_j]=0$. I am trying to show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[  \max_{1\leq j \leq n}  | \sigma_n^{1/2} X_j| > \epsilon \right]=\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[  \max_{1\leq j \leq n}  | X_j| >\frac{1}{\sigma_n^{1/2}} \epsilon \right] = 0, \quad (\forall \, \epsilon>0) $$
where $\sigma_n = \tfrac{\lambda}{n} (1 - \tfrac{\lambda}{n}) = \tfrac{\lambda(n - \lambda)}{n^2}$.

According this post, [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084313/tail-probabilities-of-identically-distributed-variables), I can show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[  \max_{1\leq j \leq n}  | X_j| > n \, \epsilon \right] = 0, \quad (\forall \, \epsilon>0)  $$

But I'm having trouble adapting the proof to my case.

**Update**

I have  $E[|X|^2]< \infty$.

$\sigma_n > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\sigma_n^{-1/2}\geqslant c_\lambda \sqrt{n}$ for some constant $c_\lambda$ depending only on $\lambda$. Therefore, it suffices to prove that
for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[  \max_{1\leq j \leq n}  | X_j| >  \epsilon\sqrt n \right] = 0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\forall\varepsilon >0, \lim_{n \to \infty}P\left[  \max_{1\leq j \leq n}Y_j >  \epsilon n \right] = 0,
$$
where $Y_j=X_j^2$, here we are in the situation of the linked post.